# Dell Latitude / Windows 7 & My Old Apple Keyboard | Still Compatible?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, keyboard, dell-latitude

I recently replaced my older Dell Latitude with a newer model. Works great with Windows 7, but now my beloved Apple keyboard doesn't function at all. My IT guys say that it's because the new Latitude runs  USB 3.0 whereas my older Latitude was 2.0. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, USB 3.0 is backwards compatible, so all USB 2.0 and USB 1.1 devices should work flawlessly with USB 3.0 ports. In practice some devices just don't work. Things to try:

- Make sure all necessary drivers are installed. Dedicated drivers obtained from manufacturer's website are preferred, as those provided by Microsoft may not be perfect.
- Check your BIOS/UEFI for any USB-related options. Try toggling USB compatibility switches.
- Try to boot Ubuntu from a flash drive or DVD and see if the keyboard works. If it does, then it's a Windows issue. Otherwise it's rather a hardware or UEFI bug.
- Connect the keyboard through a USB 2.0 hub.

If the laptop came with Windows 8.x preinstalled, then you should especially take care of drivers.